# How to open a stream to httpS URL

Tags: java, https

I want to open a stream to a httpS URL and read the data.

Kindly let me know how to do it.

Regards
Chaitanya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Sun tutorial on [Reading from / Writing to URL connection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

Opening HTTPS connection is no different from opening HTTP connection; if you need to use https-specific methods you can class cast the result of `url.openConnection()` to [HttpsURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html):

```
URL url = new URL("https://your.https.url.here/");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
```

Comment: Note that the default behaviour is to abort if a non-trusted certificate is found along the way.  Very common for developers.

Comment: We have to take care of certificates.

Comment: So you've downvoted me because I didn't guess that from your question? You've asked "how to open the stream and read data" - that's what I answered.